# auth.reminder.repository for Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I have the following lines of code

```
// Creates new password reminder token and deletes old one.
$token = app('auth.reminder.repository')->create($user);
```

The `$token` is then used to send an email and allow users to change their password.

In Laravel 5.8 the `auth.reminder.repository` does not exists.

In Laravel 4.x in was aliased to `Auth\Reminders\ReminderServiceProvider`

Need help figuring out how to update the code for Laravel 5.8.

Answer (score 0):

```
$password_broker = app(\Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker::class);

// Create reset password token.
$token = $password_broker->createToken($user);
```